# nginx location with dashes

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location

I got a nginx location like this:

```
location ^~ "/some-location/" {
    proxy_pass http://some_backend/;
}
```

This works fine, but i also want to catch some Upper- and Lowercase combinations.
I know, i could use `location ~*` to have this match case insensitive, but without, the backend won't work.

So I tried something like this:

```
location ^~ "/(some-location|Some-location|Some-Location)/" {
    proxy_pass http://some_backend/;
}
```

Unfortunately, this isn't working.

Someone have an idea, what to do?

Comment: Did you try with several location blocks - one for each alternation?

Comment: I did.This worked fine.

Comment: If it worked - you can add it as an answer.

Comment: My question was, If i could get it to Work in one Location. I could do this, with several additional Locations (Like 20 or so), but that's Not, what i wanted :)

Comment: You are trying to specify the location as regular expression alternations - but this type of location does not suppoer regular expressions. You should use `~*` and make sure there is a trailing slash in the URL. You can test your locations at https://nginx.viraptor.info/